# Creating views dynamically MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ..

[image: MySQL table]

this table gets updated with new records everytime from the client users.

What i want is to create a view for all distinct values of team_id, team_id values arent fixed .. can be in range 1-16 at 1 time and 1-8 at another time .. in any range ..

So what i want is to create views dynamically( => trigger) on every record(View name as: view_of_team + NEW.team_id) insertion in this table ..

I have tried executing create view statements in after insert triggers but MySQL wasnt just creating the trigger .. i then landed upon calling a procedure from after insert trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_view_if_not_exists_stored_proc`(IN `team_id` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
if not exists(select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE like 'VIEW' and TABLE_NAME like concat('view_of_team', team_id)) then

        SET @ViewName = concat('view_of_team', cast(team_id as char(50)));
        SET @sql = concat('create view ', @ViewName, ' as select * from mini_events_score_log where team_id=', team_id);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end if
```

and using `CALL create_view_if_not_exists_stored_proc(NEW.team_id)` inside after insert trigger for the table shown above

Executing procedure alone in my PhpMyAdmin creates views but the error arises: "Dynamic SQL not allowed in stored function or trigger" when trigger is executed after inserting a new record ..

Is there a way to create views dynamically in this case ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way what you're doing makes sense is if you believe that a MySQL VIEW stores a subset of data separately from the base table.

This is not the case. Think of a MySQL VIEW as simply an alias for a more complex query against the base table(s). There is no advantage for performance or efficiency to query a view instead of a base table.

In fact, depending on the query, MySQL may even query it *less* efficiently than querying the base table. Because some types of queries you could define a VIEW for will implicitly cause the query to create a temporary table.

There are two reasons to create a VIEW in MySQL:

- The first is to restrict access privileges, so you can grant a user access to query the VIEW, which queries just a subset of the columns or rows of the base table. The user wouldn't have direct privileges on the base table, just privileges to query the VIEW.
- The second reason is for the sake of convenience, so you can query a simple VIEW as an alias for a complex query, so you don't have to repeat the complex query many times in your app.

But in your example, the query you defined the VIEW for is itself very simple. The benefit of aliasing this query is very little.

And you'd have to generate queries against the *right* view, which means formatting the view name from user input. This sounds like an opportunity to get an SQL injection vulnerability if you're not careful.

I recommend forgetting this idea to create a view for each distinct team. Just query the base table instead, and add a WHERE clause when you query it. That's easier than choosing between hundreds of similarly-named views, and you can even use a query parameter for the team id, so you can protect yourself from SQL injection flaws.

Comment: Aha ThankYou for the reply, even i thought of not having such views .. but .. actually while insertion of records in the base table, there is alot of chaos and other stuff going on in realtime so wanted to make it easy for the DBA to auto-filter the records per distinct team .. it would be really inconvenient for him to write in the query and edit the values and fire it each time he wants to view only the desired team's data among 1k records of the base table

Comment: Well, it's either write a WHERE clause to specify a given team_id value, or write a whole *different query* to read the correct view for the respective team. I can't believe any DBA would find the former to be difficult.